# xshell randomly disconnected from linux server (Socket error Event: 32 Error: 10053)

Tags: linux, putty, disconnection, xshell

When I use xshell or any other software to connect a remote server, I sometimes see internet disconnection.

The error message is as follows.

> Socket error Event: 32 Error: 10053. Connection closing...Socket
> close.
>
> Connection closed by foreign host

Interestingly, when there is something run in the foreground, the connection usually won't be cut off (there will be a short delay for a few seconds but disconnection doesn't happen).

Does anyone know the reason? I see someone said this is due to duplicate IP?

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).